# Check if pointer is pointing to null or it's valid

Tags: c#, memory

I have to read/write a memory address but sometimes it's crashing the target program (most of the times works without crashing), I guess because it's trying to operate with an address that isn't valid.

[image]

The program just crashes and I'm not able to debug.. sometimes it can be running 3-4h without crashing and sometimes doesn't last even 5 minutes.

So my current code is this one:

```
var addy = sharp.Modules.MainModule.BaseAddress + Offsets.offset_last_watched_item;
var item = sharp.Read<int>(addy, false);
chat.Print(item.ToString());
```

And I need to do something like this:

```
var addy = sharp.Modules.MainModule.BaseAddress + Offsets.offset_last_watched_item;
if (addy != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    var item = sharp.Read<int>((IntPtr)Offsets.offset_last_watched_item);
    if (item > 0)
    {
        chat.Print(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

That's the way to check if the pointer is valid also it's return value so I don't access a region I shouldn't?

**EDIT:** forgot to add the method Print()

```
public void Print(string msg)
{
    var print = sharp.Modules.MainModule.BaseAddress + Offsets.func_print;
    sharp.Assembly.Execute(print, CallingConventions.Cdecl, msg);
}
```

Methods sharp.Read and sharp.Execute are from lib [Memorysharp](https://github.com/ZenLulz/MemorySharp)

Comment: What output do you get when it "crashes"?  If it's just an exception, you can catch it using try / catch

Comment: yeah forgot to mention updating question now

Comment: I doubt the problem is because `item` is 0. I'm assuming `item` is an `int`?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the read-call in a try/catch?

Comment: yes it's inside a try/catch but my application is not handling that exception